# javascript youtube api request cache

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels

i am having a strange problem.

I use OAuth2 and gapi.auth.authorize({client_id:'...',scope:'../youtube',immediate:false}) to log a user into my app. This method lets the user choose which of his connected accounts(identities) to use.

I retrieve user's video using gapi.client.youtube.channels.list and gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list.

later in the same app the user can click a button to choose another of his connected accounts(identities). i use again gapi.auth.authorize({client_id:'...',scope:'../youtube',immediate:false}) method.

the problem is that after successfull change of the account the gapi.client.youtube.channels.list method returns the cached result from the first call.

some remarks:
-in ie 11 it works fine
- in google chrome, if i disable the cache from developers tools it also works fine
- before the call to channels.list i call /oauth2/v2/tokeninfo and /plus/v1/people/me and they both return correct results, that is the second account's data

is there any way to correct this?
thank you.

Comment: i read at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#etags that "The client libraries for Google APIs differ in their support of ETags. For example, the JavaScript client library supports ETags via a whitelist for allowed request headers that includes If-Match and If-None-Match. The whitelist allows normal browser caching to occur so that if a resource's ETag has not changed, the resource can be served from the browser cache. The Obj-C client, on the other hand, does not support ETags." How can one set these whitelists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone can overcome this by using XMLHttpRequest( see https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors) . It's probably a bug of javascript YouTube api.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to introduce a silly extra parameter on the request to cheat Google's system... Or at least that's my impression, because it seems to work consistently:

I just add it to the URL:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?mine=true" +
  "&part=" + encodeURIComponent("id,snippet") +
  "&key=" + encodeURIComponent(API_KEY) +
  "&random=" + encodeURIComponent(Math.random().toString())
```

Here's the full example:

```js
  refreshChannels(): Promise<YoutubeChannel[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            this.channels = JSON.parse(xhr.response).items.map(ch => new YoutubeChannel().deserialize(ch));
            console.log("[Youtube][loadChannels] Got some channels:");
            console.log(this.channels);
            this.onReceivedYoutubeChannels.next(this.channels);
            resolve(this.channels);
          } else {
            reject(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
          }
        }
      };

      xhr.onerror = () => reject();

      const user = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get();
      const oAuthToken = user.getAuthResponse().access_token;
      xhr.open(
        "GET",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?mine=true&part=" +
          encodeURIComponent("id,snippet") +
          "&key=" +
          encodeURIComponent(API_KEY) +
          "&random=" + encodeURIComponent(Math.random().toString())
      );
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + oAuthToken);
      xhr.send();
    });
  }
```

I get different ETags. I saw as well a Cache-Control response header that might be caching too?

`cache-control: private, max-age=300, must-revalidate, no-transform`

With my solution I can overcome it. If someone understands why it would be great if could elaborate more on this solution.